# Apache ignite geo spacial queries examples

Tags: geolocation, ignite

I am looking for an example using Apache Ignite where we have a bunch of geo points like example locations in a city a we do a query for points close to a certain point within a radius.

I have found only an example of POLYGON search at:
https://dzone.com/articles/geospatial-queries-with-apachereg-ignite

Thank you, kindly
Luis Oscar

Answer (score 1):

Ignite uses [Java Topology Suite](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/) to support spatial queries. As far as I know, circular geometry is not supported by JTS.

But you can still approximate a circle with a polygon. If you need exactly the points, that fit into a circle, you can query for points, that lay in a circumscribed regular polygon and after that filter out the points, that have greater distance, than the specified radius. The filtering may be performed in code outside the query.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you could use a "greater rectangle or square" which is the smaller rectangle containing your circle. Then loop through the results with the isWithinDistance(...) method from your orignal point to filter the point inside the rectangle but not inside your circle.

However as ignite uses JTS, which is a planar representation, according to my tests, you can't make accurate search with spherical(or ellipsoid) projection (like WGS84) and many results would be wrong. Most likely the Polygon search is not accurate and the isWithinDistance won't filter correctly, unless you are searching something at less than 10meters from the original point.